# How can I shift array element using a for loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to shift all the elements of an array to the left, so that the first element would become the last element, the second becomes the first, the third the second, etc. I know about the `circshift` commands, but I would like to do this using a for loop.

Here's what I did.

```
old=[]
n=length(old)
for i=1;i<(n-1);i=i+1;
    for j=2;j<n;j=j+1;
        new(j)=old(i)
    end
end
```

But it of course didn't work. I'm having trouble figuring out to make an array of n elements, without specifying n, which is why I used old=[], but I think that created an array of 0 elements.

How can I make this code work?

Comment: Sorry, but using a loop for this in Matlab is abusing the language. Try `newArray = oldArray([2:end 1]);`

Comment: I realize a loop might not be necessary. I'm just trying to get comfortable with the language, so I want to be able to do this using a loop, just for the sake of knowing how.

Answer (score 2):

So your irst step is to learn how to specify a [for loop in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html), what you have is like C syntax. This is not Matlab syntax at all.

The following is how to do it using forloops but this is not good matlab programming. You could easily do it without loops too.

```
vec = 1:10;
temp = [];
shiftby = 2;

for ii = 1:shiftby %Each iteration shifts by one
    temp = vec(end); %Store the last element of vec
    for jj = size(vec, 2):-1:2; %inner loop must shift each element from the end to element 2
        vec(jj) = vec(jj-1);
    end
    vec(1) = temp; %put the old end value at the beginning
end
```

but you could also just do this which is a much more Matlabesque way to code it:

```
vec = [vec(end - shiftby + 1: end), vec(1:end - shiftby)]
```

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I knew I wasn't doing something right but I didn't realize I was that off. Once I create a for loop, if I want to run it to see it in action, how would I go about this?

Comment: You need to do a basic matlab tutorial. Find one online. Look up how to create and run mfiles. If you want to see the output try disp(vec) or just look at vec in the workspace variable browser. Also try and understand why the single line I posted at the end is the same as the loop. You'll probably aslo find its faster as is very often the case in matlab. Loops are usually discouraged comapred to such 'vectorized' alternatives. Lastly if this has helped, please marked the little tick so people know its solved and also feel free to upvote it too if you think is was a worthy answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling a loop was an inefficient way to do this, but I wanted to try for this particular exercise. Thanks a lot for all the help. I can't upvote as it seems my reputation is too low, but I think I'll be around these forums much more from now on. So when I can, I'll be back to send an upvote your way. Thanks again!

Comment: I see I was shifting the wrong way, let me know if you can't adapt my code to get it to shift left instead of right. Also the code H.Muster posted in his comment is even better, make sure you understand what he's done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid specifying the `n` length of the array, you have to give it as an input argument in a function.
For example you can do something like this:

```
function new = shiftLeft(old)
n = length(old);

for i =1:n
new(i) = old(mod(i,n)+1);
end

return
```

So with this one, if you have an array for example `old = [1 2 3 4];` you can will get something like `new = [2 3 4 1];`

`mod(a,b)` is the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator, you can find more information if you type `help mod`.

Comment: So probably a noobie question, but, in order to use 'function' I have to create it as a .m file and then call it, right? I can't just enter that in the command window, I think.

Comment: Yes. You create a new .m file. It's recommended that you use the same name as the name of your function, for example `shiftLeft.m`. Then you can call it from the command line like this for example:
`array1 = [1 2 3 4 5];`
`array2 = shiftLeft(array1);`
The only thing you have to care is that Matlab's active folder is the folder where the .m file is, otherwise it won't find it and show you an error message.

Comment: You can create an .m file without making it a function. Then, when you run it, you get the same result as if you where just typing in the command line and all the variables you declare stay in Matlab's environment after the script's execution is finished.